# override a css style

Tags: css, custom-background

I have the following line in the original theme style.css file:

```
background: none repeat scroll 0px 0px #CCC;
```

In my child-theme.. I want to delete the "background: line..

But how?

**Update:**

OK to make things clear....

As I'm using a child theme with an own style.css file.. This settings in the style.css file override the ones in the parent theme.

In the theme's style sheet the following is stated...

```
.content-ver-sep {
     background: none repeat scroll 0px 0px #CCC;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
     clear: both;
     height: 1px;
}
```

but for the child theme's style.css sheet I don't wont a background declaration or a border bottom.. So I know how to override it (with another value) but how do i delete or ignore these settings.

Comment: Why do you want to *delete* it, as opposed to overriding it?

Answer (score 1):

You can not delete or ignore default styling in a child theme. You must override the declaration.

```
 .content-ver-sep {
 background: transparent !important;
 border-bottom: none !important;
 clear: both;
 height: 1px;
 }
```

this should do the trick -